# Wordpress custom PHP file returning 404 when accessed

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, http-status-code-404

I have custom scripts running (ajax with some functions).
Problem is that not all .php files are loaded...

When I access the URL/whatever.php it shows 404 not found.

I tried changing htaccess file, tried to move that file around to different directories. I can however access images this way - so there must be something wrong with the rewrite maybe?

````
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress```

404 page displaying...
````

Comment: Where is your whatever.php file? In the WP root?

Comment: I tried to put it any where - root, plugins, theme... always 404. I tried to update permalinks and so on... I disabled all plugins and theme and its all the same

Comment: It should be in root if you want to call it as URL/whatever.php and it should work that way. Are other Wordpress pages working?

Comment: Pages/Posts are working its just .php files that are not working

Comment: A workaround, could be to create an password protected page, and create a template for that page where you can rund your functions.

Comment: @stender thanks for input but this is not suitable answer.

Comment: Thats why I didn't post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

To `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_custom_function', 'custom_function_init' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_custom_function', 'custom_function_init' );

function custom_function_init() {
    $fields = $_REQUEST;
    //do whatever you want
    echo 'return something';
    die();
}
```

To 'footer.php'

```
<script>
    var ajax_url = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
</script>
```

and your ajax things, somehere in JS file

```
function do_ajax(data) {
    if( xhr != null ) {
        xhr.abort();
        xhr = null;
    }

    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        timeout: 3600,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: ({
            action:'your_custom_function',
            data:data
        }),

        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log(data)   

        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
            console.log( 'The following error occured: ' + textStatus, errorThrown );
        },
        complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input... I will reply what my website replied '404 not found admin-ajax.php'

Comment: Can you provide what you have in fuctions.php, footer and JS?

Comment: All is correct - it was tested on another site (same server) and its working. Its not working on this site for unknown reason